# About the paper "Elements of Morse theory on Alexandrov spaces"

Tags: reference-request, alexandrov-geometry

I am learning some structure theorems in Alexandrov geometry and the paper "Elements of Morse theory on Alexandrov spaces" by G. Perelman is frequently quoted. However, I am unable to find the English version of this important article (except for the Russian original).

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the math, but in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0703002.pdf, it is stated that the theorems in the paper you cite (which was published in Russian) were generalized in this paper: https://anton-petrunin.github.io/papers/alexandrov/Cstructure.pdf

Comment: English translation is at St. Petersburg Math. J. 5 (1994), no. 1, 205–213, I can't find it on the web though

Comment: only issues since 2004 have been [digitized](https://www.ams.org/journals/spmj/all_issues.html) by the AMS; the 1994 issue has been [digitized](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/002581525) by HathiTrust, but copyright restrictions prevent full text download (only limited search) --- so I presume you'll need to contact a library...

Comment: I can send you a Russian version of the paper and perhaps you can use Google Translate on your smartphone to do the translation (if you have the app). Just point at the text and the phone will do the translation. It is like "Harry Potter". I am still looking for the English translation.